# split a string to an array (each character) - Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift, split, character

I've got a little problem. I want to split a String in an array of characters, where I can work on each character.

For example:

```
"Hello"
    arrayofstring[0] ->H
    arrayofstring[1] ->e
    arrayofstring[2] ->l
    arrayofstring[3] ->l
    arrayofstring[4] ->o
```

I am thankful for every help.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your code and any error messages!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
    let string : String = "Hello"
    let arrayofstring = string.characters.map { (Character) -> Character in
      return Character
    } 
   println(arrayofstring)
```

Comment: I found an solution out of two related questions, its right below.
Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 12):

Unless I'm missing something, it's easier than either of the other answers:

```
let arrayofstring = Array("Hello".characters)
```

Comment: That creates an array of Character not an array of String.